# Create `MenuItem`s having similar structure

Tags: java, javafx

I've create several `MenuItem`s with similar structures, note where `Topic` is a `enum` class.

The structure looks like this:

```
    CheckBox business = new CheckBox("Business");
    // add Topic to filteredTopics set when box is selcted
    business.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if(((CheckBox)event.getSource()).isSelected()) {
                filteredTopics.add(Topic.BUSINESS);
            } else {
                filteredTopics.remove(Topic.BUSINESS);
            }
        }
    });

    CheckBox international = new CheckBox("International");
    // add Topic to filteredTopics set when box is selcted
    international.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if(((CheckBox)event.getSource()).isSelected()) {
                filteredTopics.add(Topic.INTERNATIONAL);
            } else {
                filteredTopics.remove(Topic.INTERNATIONAL);
            }
        }
    }); 

    //etc like Sport, Domestic...
```

is there a much compact way to code these `MenuItem`s, am I hard-coding the topics? As the requirements say *The topic controls should be programmed, not hard-coded (that is, the program should itself determine the number and name of all controls from the Topic enum type).*

Please let me know if need further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the checkboxes in an array one for each topic in the enum.

Something like this.

```
List<CheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
for(Topic t : Topic.values()) {
   Checkbox c = new Checkbox(t.toString());
   c.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          if((CheckBox)event.getSource()).isSelected()) {
              filteredTopics.add(t);
          }
          else {
             filteredTopics.remove(t);
          }
      }
   });
   checkboxes.add(c);
}
```

It might also make sense to create a small extension class for the checkboxes that allows you to store the topic so that it's easier to access later but you can use the order of the values to figure it out with this setup.